# Automatic positioning of cite index

Tags: citing

Is there a way to make LaTeX automatically move all my numbered (superscript) citations to after the periods, commas and semicolons?

e.g. I like to type (and so often accidentally type)

```
Sentence here \cite{paper}.
```

and want it to always produce the same output as

```
Sentence here. \cite{paper}
```

Superscript cites are part of the jasatex class that I wish to use for submission to the Journal of the Acoustical Society of America (unfortunately the class doesn't enforce this index positioning, nor is it actively maintained). It uses Natbib.

I can see from another post that the class for Phys. Rev. allows this option e.g. the argument `citeautoscript` in `\usepackage[aps,prb,citeautoscript]{revtex4-1}`, but I don't know how to do this with my class.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This functionality is available using the `cite` package if *not* using `natbib`, and in the [`natmove`](http://ctan.org/pkg/natmove) package for use with `natbib`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@ARTICLE{Pickett2009,
  author = {Tard, Cédric and Pickett, Christopher J.},
  title = {Structural and Functional Analogues of the Active Sites
    of the [{Fe}]-, [{NiFe}]-, and [{FeFe}]-Hydrogenases},
  journaltitle = {Chem. Rev.},
  year = {2009},
  volume = {109},
  number = {6},
  pages = {2245-2274},
  doi = {10.1021/cr800542q},
}

\end{filecontents*}
\usepackage[numbers,super]{natbib}
\usepackage{natmove}
\begin{document}
Some text \cite{Pickett2009}.
\bibliography{\jobname}
\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Note: I wrote `natmove`, but the code is essentially that from `cite`.